# value of 'this' when function is called differently

Tags: javascript

On this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

It is warned that the value of `this` will be different when calling the `modifyText()` function when using `addEventListener()` as opposed to applying the event using `onclick=''` directly in the HTML.  In the page linked above, note the first example (actually it's the second), and then the following section titled '**The value of `this` within the handler**'.

I decided to test this, but cannot find a difference.  What am I doing wrong?

addeventlistener2.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DOM Event Example 1</title>
<style type="text/css">
  #t { border: 1px solid red }
  #t1 { background-color: pink; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Function to change the content of t2
  function modifyText(new_text) {
    var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
    t2.innerHTML = new_text + '<br />this: <b>' + this + '</b>';
  }

  // Function to add event listener to t
  function load() {
    var el = document.getElementById("t");
    el.addEventListener("click", function(){modifyText("body onload")}, false);
  }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="load();">

<p>has onload in body.</p>

<table id="t">
  <tr><td id="t1">one</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="t2">two</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

addeventlistener2.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DOM Event Example 2</title>
<style type="text/css">
  #t { border: 1px solid red }
  #t1 { background-color: pink; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Function to change the content of t2
  function modifyText(new_text) {
    var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
    t2.innerHTML = new_text + '<br />this: <b>' + this + '</b>';
  }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>has onclick in table:</p>

<table id="t" onclick='modifyText("boo!")'>
  <tr><td id="t1">one</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="t2">two</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can you expect to find a difference in the value of the `this` reference if you never even access it in either case?

Comment: I put `this` into `t2.innerHTML`.

Comment: It should be clear from the example already. You pass an anonymous function which calls `modifyText`, whereas in the documentation, they pass `modifyText` directly to `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the addEventListener example you are wrapping modifyText inside an other function. All the `this` magic will happen to that outer function and modifyText won't see any of it.

Try passing modifyText directly to addEventListener

```
node.addEventListener('click', modifyText);
//and make sure to change modifyText to receive no parameters or it wont work :)
```

---

Or use the power of closures if you still want to be able to choose the parameter:

```
function modifyText(new_text) {
    return function(){
        var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
        t2.innerHTML = new_text + '<br />this: <b>' + this + '</b>';
    };
}

//addEventListener(modifyText('txt'))
//versus
//onclick=modifyText('txt')()
```

Comment: Right you are.  It works when using the function reference.  But I couldn't get the second "closures" sample to work at all.  No error, either.

Comment: Did you change the commented stuff to the propper version? I think I typed the closure bit correctly at least...

Answer (score 0):

Hej this referce to the object witch the function is stored.
so in both your examples this refers to window the global object.

test:

```
t2.innerHTML = new_text + '<br />this: <b>' + (this === window) + '</b>';
```

will write true

Comment: `this` is set according to how a function is called, not according where a function is "stored". Functions bound to events with `addEventListener` will have `this` set to the element the event was triggered on.

Comment: but it has the same result ... if you pass it to addEventListener then it is put in another context. Yea ofc its dependents on how its called.

Comment: Well it has the same result in OP's code because the function bound by addEventListener immediately calls another function and doesn't set `this` for _that_ function.